# random() function only spitting out big numbers

Tags: c, random

I am using the random() function, and I was wondering if there is a reason that I'm always getting 8-10 digit numbers. I just want to make sure there isn't something wrong with my program. Thanks.

Here's the function:

```
void random_array(int* p, int size) {
    /*seed random number generator */
    srandom(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        *(p+i) = random();
}
```

Comment: Note the standard C pseudo-random number generator functions are named `srand` and `rand`, respectively.

Comment: @milleniumbug: `random()` and `srandom()` are defined in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/initstate.html).

Answer (score 4):

Well, mathematically the chance that you will get a big number is a lot more than the chance for a (relatively) small one. For instance, if you pick a random number with (1-4) digits, the chance that it would be in the range (0-99) would be only 1 %.

With that said, if you want smaller numbers, you can take the random modulo some certain number:

```
a = random() % 100; // this will give you a random number from 0 to 99
b = 10 + random() % 15; // random number from 10 to 24
```

Answer (score 3):

Number of 8-10 digits numbers: 10,000,000,000 - 100,000,000 = 9,900,000,000 (9.9 billion)

Number of 0-7 digit numbers: 10,000,000 (10 million)

In other words, there are 990 8-10 digit numbers for every 1 0-7 digit number. Therefore, you can expect to get about 1 0-7 digit number for every 990 8-10 digit numbers.

Put simply, *it's because there are more of them*.

Answer (score 0):

How large a number were you expecting to receive from `random()`?

If you want to limit the size of the number generated, simply use a modulus operator to limit the result to the remainder (in the example below a number from 0 to 999):

```
*(p+i) = random() % 1000;
```

Comment: Using the remainder is not a particularly good way to get smaller random numbers if the quality of randomness is a concern.

Comment: @Arkku Thanks for your comment, but what makes you say that when the chance of receiving any single remainder within the set is equal?

Comment: @MartinParkin: It is not equal because the span of numbers returned by `random` is not usually a multiple of the desired span. On top of that, all the excess values are mapped to the low end of the destination interval, skewing the distribution. And, on top of that, common (but poor) generators have low randomness in their low bits, and taking a remainder modulo a multiple of a power of two inherits those low bits.

Comment: @MartinParkin The thing is, for most configurations it *isn't*. Look up modulo bias. As an example, suppose `random()` outputs numbers between 0 and 1000 inclusive, then `random() % 1000` is twice as likely to produce 0 as it is to produce any of 1..999 respectively.

Comment: @delnan I accept the point, however given that random is generating a random number between 0 and 2^64 I don't see how this can become a significant factor.  Having just tested this with a piece of code to generate a random 64-bit number with a modulo of 1000 over 10,000,000,000 iterations, I see no statistical significance between the remainders generated.  However, I feel we digress somewhat from the original query.  I would be happy to explore this with you offline though if you care to drop me an email.

Comment: A graph of the modulo bias is here: http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/16/how-much-bias-is-introduced-by-the-remainder-technique/ You are correct that if the range is enormous compared to the modulus then the bias is very small.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for sharing that article, it was most illuminating with regards to how the bias occurs and why it can become a problem in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically it is likely since big numbers are..well.. more than small ones, so yes. It is much more likely to get such a number.

To generate a custom-interval random number use something like

http://ideone.com/bWbBgJ

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Generate random numbers in the min-max interval
void random_array(int* p, int size, int min, int max) {
    /*seed random number generator */
    srandom(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        *(p+i) = (random() % max) + min;
}

int main(void) {

    int array[3];
    random_array(array, 3, 0, 12);

    printf("%d\n", array[0]);
    printf("%d\n", array[1]);
    printf("%d\n", array[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A big seed need not cause big outputs, beyond (possibly) the first one. In fact, that would be indicative of a *very* poor PRNG, even poorer than the LCG commonly used in C implementations.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the seed generator algorithm for that function so I'll just stick with the mathematical definition I'm sure of. Thanks for the info by the way!

Comment: Don't forget to `#include <stdlib.h>`